# How do I add definition to the cell borders in an HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

This table:

```
<table border="1">
<tbody><tr>
<td></td>
<td>Grokkability</td>
<td>PIA Factor*</td>
<td>FancyPantsiness</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>XML</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Code</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Auto-Wiring</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

...looks as I want it to on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/9AX8H/), but on Code Project it has lost its cell formatting (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/711127/Swapping-Out-Concrete-Implementations-of-Interface)

What must I do to force the cell boundaries to be visible?

Comment: not sure - maybe you could try with inline css? main.min css file removes borders...

Comment: They're probably using a CSS reset that you'll need to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use css..

```
<table class="border">
<tbody><tr>
<th></th>
<th>Grokkability</th>
<th>PIA Factor*</th>
<th>FancyPantsiness</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>XML</th>
<td>10</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Code</th>
<td>10</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Auto-Wiring</th>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

Your css

.border {
    border: solid 1pt;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.border th{
border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #34B767;
}

.border td{
border: 1px solid;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

[image]